# Binding multiple files to a List using ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to bind to a list of files in a model like that, using a multipart form/data passing the file[0], ..., file[n], etc. as keys. My model looks like this:

```
public class MergeModel
{
    [Required]            
    public IEnumerable<IFormFile> File { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("merge")]
public IActionResult Merge(MergeModel model)
{

}
```

Unfortunately when I make a post using Postman like this:

[image]

I get a `null` in `File` property. However if I make a request like this:

[image]

it works perfectly. Is there any way to bind to file[0] etc. keys?

Comment: may I know why do you want to do this?

Comment: That's just my project requirement :)

Comment: I removed the .NET Core from tags and title as the issue seems unrelated to .NET Core but is a ASP.NET Core (which is something completely different than .NET Core)